# Greenshot-how to save all or export all open windows, to selected destination?

Tags: windows-8.1, export, greenshot

When screenshotting with the [Greenshot app](http://getgreenshot.org/) I often get too many open windows to find or organise them, and too many to view properly in a cascade/stack of windows, or a taskbar jump list.

1. Is there a way to save them all? Then I can view/preview/rename/cull, and organise in File Explorer.
2. Sometimes it would work better to export/send all windows to Word.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use greenshot when recording multiple screenshots.

Use Windows native Steps Recorder - can

1. auto-record (numbered step + timestamp + description + screenshot of each action) AND/OR
2. manual record screenshots with custom comment (Pause record to record ONLY manual screenshots)

Recording is sent to a zip file. Extract the .mht file, 
- click opens it in Internet Explorer.  Preview and save individual screenshots.
- OR open it in Word, edit as required.

(Cons- cant crop or annotate the screenshots while recording, (I use word macros for that)
but does highlight selected area in the comment function.)
[image: sample of word doc]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no feature to bulk export all open editor windows at once, neither file system or Word. Do you know that you can choose a different default target for your screenshots than the editor? So you can easily save every screenshot to a file directly. You can also select multiple, e.g. save to file **and** open in image editor (see screenshot).

However, if you need to export screenshots with annotations from open editor windows, the fastest way is currently to do one after another using shortcurts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, repeatedly, until all windows are saved and closed.

[image: Configuring multiple screenshot destinations]

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes I did, but usually prefer to saveas, unless I get bogged down then have to do something else! -)